# Testing a complicated method

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I'm working on a checkers implementation where I have dozens of easily tested methods, but I'm not sure how to test my main #play_game method. Where most of my methods have easily determined inputs and outputs, and are, therefore, easy to test, this method is multifaceted and really doesn't have an easily discernible output. Here is the code:

```
def play_game
    puts @gui.intro

    while(game_over? == false)
      message = nil
      @gui.render_board(@board)
      @gui.move_request
      player_input = gets 
      coordinates = UserInput.translate_move_request_to_coordinates(player_input) 

      message = MoveCheck.move_validator(coordinates[0], coordinates[1], coordinates[2], coordinates[3])
      puts message unless (message.nil? or message == "jumping move")
      if(message == nil or message == "jumping move")
        @current_player = switch_player unless (message == "jumping move" and jump_available? == true)
      end
    end
    puts @gui.display_game_ending_message  
  end
```

So how can I test this (using RSpec) or should I not worry about it and really on my otherwise comprehensive testing?

Comment: FWIW, note that if you'd done this test-first, you'd have easily testable methods as a matter of course.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser, moreover, you'd also already have the tests!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All `play_game` is really doing is running the game loop. What you are really looking to test is what happens *inside* the game loop. The easiest way to do that is to break the content of the game loop down into more easily testable methods.

Once you have the game loop as just a series of methods, you can then much more easily test each of them in isolation.

Comment: Your advice is very sound, but I don't understand it in the context of the question, as the code already uses small methods (render, move, translate, ...), I don't see how the OP is gonna split them more. As I see it, the real problem is that he has a loop that runs the whole game, which is indeed difficult to test.

Comment: Absolutely!  You should also consider the fact that not everything is easily testable and not everything should be tested.  Be pragmatic about what to test...break down logic into different methods that are testable. If you have a method that prints messages and then calls a method that does the heavy lifting and does that over and over again, consider not testing it if it's not huge and consider testing the underlying methods. You should however consider testing the entire flow (calling method A, B, C in that order and so on). I hope this makes sense...else I can elaborate more with examples.

Comment: @tokland as mentioned above, the logic of what happens inside the run loop should be broken down to separate methods.  for example: the jumping move check should be it's own method...it's more readable and more testable.  You can test all scenarios that lead up to that method without having to touch the game loop!

Comment: @vinnybad: true, you can no doubt improve this main loop more and split it into more separate methods, but at the end the main logic of a game must be also tested, otherwise you can end up with a bunch of  small methods working all fine and a broken main loop!

Comment: @tokland I see what you're trying to say.  Let me try saying it another way: if you break up your logic into higher level methods, you can create every input scenario to each of the higher level methods...and therefore you're testing your main loop.  you should consider putting logic from your main loop into higher level methods if possible...and that way it can be tested.  keep in mind not every method is meant to be tested too...imagine testing a kernel scheduler!  Fun fact I heard from a guy at a conference: linux kernel doesn't have unit tests.  companies find bugs and report them.

Answer (score 4):

I'd move all the code inside the *while*-loop to a separate method. This way you could easily test it by feeding it with different *old* game states as input and checking that they are processed successfully (to get the *new* game state). Note that code that follows functional-programming principles is easier to test (`new_state = process(old_state)`), but anyway, you still can do testing as it is, checking that `@gui` is updated the way you expect given a previous state.

Your main `play_game` method would be now as simple as:

```
def play_game
  process(@gui) until game_over?
end
```

[edit] Let me show a real example. To play with Raphael.js and CoffeeScript I wrote a Reversi engine ([reversi.coffee](https://github.com/tokland/netreversi/blob/master/client/reversi.coffee) and here the [spec](https://github.com/tokland/netreversi/blob/master/client/spec/reversi.spec.coffee)). The main loop code in your question is here isolated in a stateless function: `move`. So I can do `new_state = move(old_state)` and test it with all the pairs *old_state*/*expected_new_states* I see fit.

Comment: Feeding in known game state pairs, as well as the action(s) taken, is a good idea. Especially if you build this into a testing framework, you can easily run recurrence tests against old bugs that are found in edge-case game states, as well as test the common states or subtle variations on them as needed.